Xubuntu one ID has lost desktop background and icons
Suddenly one ID on my Xubuntu 24.04 system has lost it's background and icons.  The Whisker menu still works.  I can start applicatons either through the Whisker menu or from a terminal session.  ~/Desktop still contains the various icons that should display.  Also the 'panels' at the top and bottom are visible and - work. What can I do to get the desktop back to normal. I tried changing the desktop background - same result, it's always a black screen

There may be corrupted data in the session cache folder.
Open a terminal and run in it:
xfdesktop

If the desktop appears and the icons are visible, there is corrupted data in the cache folder, to fix this run in the terminal:
rm -R ~/.cache/sessions/*

Log out and log back in, the icons and wallpaper should appear on the desktop.
Log off the corrupted ID
Log on another ID with a terminal session such as telnet
From that ID, issue a killall command to insure all processes of the corrupted ID are gone
On that telnet session, switch user to the corrupted id in order to remove all session cache as per the answer:
 rm -R /home/{corrupted ID}/.cache/sessions/*

Now upon logging back in, the corrupted ID is working

Thanks, so far, it looks like this is the answer.  The true desktop did appear in the temporary desktop created by the command xfdesktop.  After running the command to clear the sessions corruption then logging off- when I logged back on the problem persisted.

It persisted until I performed the additional steps added to the question (since I can't edit your excellent answer)
